# How to Update Document Body Content using OpenXML SDk 2.6

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to update document content using OpenXML v2.0 using below code.

```
                Using lobjRptOPDoc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mstrRptOPDocPath, True)
                    Dim lobjupdatedbodycontent As New Body(ldomRptDocContent.DocumentElement.InnerXml)
                    lobjRptOPDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body = lobjupdatedbodycontent
                    lobjRptOPDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save()
                End Using
```

When I refer OpenXML SDK 2.6 above code is not working well. As I am trying to use OpenXML PowerTools, I have to use OpenXML SDK v2.6.

How to update document body content using OpenXML v2.6

Comment: I have this exact same issue. I can edit the document just fine but for what ever reason it does not want to save the changes when calling Save() but when I use the 2.5 SDK it works perfectly.

Comment: Just try to add missing library by downloading it from Internet. I guess missing library is System.IO

Comment: I added this using nuget, so it installed all relevent libraries including the System.IO. Everything builds and runs just fine. When running it mailmerges correctly but when I save the document using the Save() Function it does save it.